# Jackson add wrapper based on field values

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, xml-serialization

I have a class like below:

```
@JsonRootName("ASSETS")
public class Assets{
    String val1;
    String val2;
}
```

Unfortunately I need to serialize it to something like this:

```
<ASSETS>
   <ASSET>
      <val1_val2>
         <val1>x</val1>
         <val2>y</val2>
      </val1_val2>
   </ASSET>
   <ASSET>
      <val1_val2>
         <val1>x</val1>
         <val2>y</val2>
      </val1_val2>
   </ASSET>
</ASSETS>
```

I can get it to the point where I have a list of `ASSET` objects inside `ASSETS`, but how do I add that extra wrapper that's a composite of two of the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write custom serialiser. To do that, extend `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` class. Also, to create extra wrap element use [startWrappedValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/ser/ToXmlGenerator.html#startWrappedValue-javax.xml.namespace.QName-javax.xml.namespace.QName-) method. Example code could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

        Assets assets = new Assets();
        assets.getAssets().add(new Asset());
        assets.getAssets().add(new Asset());

        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(assets));
    }
}

class AssetXMLSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Asset> {

    private final QName wrapper = new QName("val1_val2");
    @Override
    public void serialize(Asset value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ToXmlGenerator xmlGen = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;

        xmlGen.writeStartObject();
        xmlGen.startWrappedValue(wrapper, wrapper);
        xmlGen.writeStringField("val1", value.getVal1());
        xmlGen.writeStringField("val2", value.getVal2());
        xmlGen.finishWrappedValue(wrapper, wrapper);
        xmlGen.writeEndObject();

    }
}

@JsonRootName("ASSETS")
class Assets {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ASSET")
    private List<Asset> assets = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters, toString
}

@JsonSerialize(using = AssetXMLSerializer.class)
class Asset {
    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<ASSETS>
  <ASSET>
    <val1_val2>
      <val1>x</val1>
      <val2>y</val2>
    </val1_val2>
  </ASSET>
  <ASSET>
    <val1_val2>
      <val1>x</val1>
      <val2>y</val2>
    </val1_val2>
  </ASSET>
</ASSETS>
```

### Solution with using default serialiser for a huge bean

To use default bean serialiser for an `Asset` class you need to use `BeanSerializerModifier` and register it using `SimpleModule`. We need to invoke `serializeFields` method which is protected, so I created `ExpandXmlBeanSerializer` just to make it public so we can use it in our implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.XmlBeanSerializer;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule assetModule = new SimpleModule();
        assetModule.setSerializerModifier(new LoopBackBeanSerializerModifier());

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.registerModule(assetModule);
        xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

        Assets assets = new Assets();
        assets.getAssets().add(new Asset("x0", "y0"));
        assets.getAssets().add(new Asset("x1", "y1"));

        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(assets));
    }
}

class LoopBackBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == Asset.class) {
            return new AssetXMLSerializer(new ExpandXmlBeanSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer));
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}

class ExpandXmlBeanSerializer extends XmlBeanSerializer {

    public ExpandXmlBeanSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeFields(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen0, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        super.serializeFields(bean, gen0, provider);
    }
}

class AssetXMLSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Asset> {

    private final QName wrapper;
    private final ExpandXmlBeanSerializer baseSerializer;

    public AssetXMLSerializer(ExpandXmlBeanSerializer baseSerializer) {
        this.baseSerializer = Objects.requireNonNull(baseSerializer);
        String fields = String.join("_",
                Stream.of(Asset.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .map(Field::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        this.wrapper = new QName(fields);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Asset value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        ToXmlGenerator xmlGen = (ToXmlGenerator) gen;

        xmlGen.writeStartObject();
        xmlGen.startWrappedValue(wrapper, wrapper);
        baseSerializer.serializeFields(value, gen, serializers);
        xmlGen.finishWrappedValue(wrapper, wrapper);
        xmlGen.writeEndObject();

    }
}

@JsonRootName("ASSETS")
class Assets {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ASSET")
    private List<Asset> assets = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Asset {
    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    public Asset(String val1, String val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

See also:

1. [Jackson xml and json root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634080/jackson-xml-and-json-root-element)
2. [Using Jackson to add XML attributes to manually-built node-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060797/using-jackson-to-add-xml-attributes-to-manually-built-node-tree)
3. [Multiple Jackson XML Custom (XMLStreamWriter) Serialisers throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275271/multiple-jackson-xml-custom-xmlstreamwriter-serialisers-throws-exception)
4. [SpringBoot: Consume & Produce XML with a Custom Serializer + Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184442/springboot-consume-produce-xml-with-a-custom-serializer-deserializer)
5. [Jackson deserialization SNS message error MismatchedInputException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58207507/51591)

Comment: This works! Any tip to handle very large numbers of fields? (instead of manually putting in var1, var2, etc)

Comment: While I don't love that the solution uses reflection, I really appreciate that you dug deep on this one for me, thank you so much! This saved my butt.

Comment: @Steve, reflection is used only to generate wrapper name. You can do that in other way if reflection is too "strong" for this job.

Comment: As I'm reading it more closely, I can see that. Thanks again, this is a great solution!